# php - input doesnt show the full value

Tags: php, html, css, input

I'm trying to put input value, which is called from base.

```
<input class=\"title\" name=\"title\" value=".$edit['title']." />
```

Title is : New York Welcome! But it shows just New. If i write NewYorkWelcome! it shows right, but when there are spaces - no. 
I just tried to echo the $edit['title'] not in input - it shows correctly. Very strange problem. Please, any solution?

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like?

Comment: From where are you getting the data?

Comment: At a guess, you need to wrap the value in quotes. `value=\"".$edit['title']."\"` Otherwise, your browser will read the first word as the value, and the rest as extra attributes of the input tag.

Comment: +1 @andrewsi. @OP-> try `<input class=\"title\" name=\"title\" value='".$edit['title']."' />`

Comment: Yes there was that problem. When i write <input class=\"title\" name=\"title\" value=\"$edit['title']\" /> it says : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

Comment: try `<input class=\"title\" name=\"title\" value=\"".$edit['title']."\" />`

Comment: @NinpoYou - if Fallen's comment doesn't help, could you edit your question and include a little more code?

Answer (score 4):

If the string is delimited by double quotes, you must escape those as you did with the previous attributes:

```
<input class=\"title\" name=\"title\" value=\"{$edit['title']}\" />
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

Comment: For me it's working. And by the way, when using this method: hope for the best. If the value inside $edit['title'] contains `""`-es itself, you're screwed ;) Try escaping the values before printing them. I'm thinking about `htmlentities` or such.